# SQL Get matching values from other table and show in main table

Tags: c#, sql, ms-access

I'm trying to do some SQL in C# along with an Access Database. I have two tables. Main Table and a Second Table:

```
MAIN TABLE
DoubleValue |        |        |        |
----------------------------------------
1,40        |        |        |        |
1,80        |        |        |        |
2,00        |        |        |        |
1,80        |        |        |        |
1,60        |        |        |        |
1,60        |        |        |        |
----------------------------------------

SECOND TABLE
DoubleValue | Points | Weight |
-------------------------------
1,00        | 100    | 2      |
1,20        | 98     | 2      |
1,40        | 96     | 2      |
1,60        | 94     | 2      |
1,80        | 92     | 2      |
2,00        | 90     | 2      |
-------------------------------
```

I need to find all matching rows in "SECOND TABLE" based on the column "Double Value". Then for the rows that matches I want to get the value in columns "Points" and "Weight" as well as multplie those two columns and create a columns with the name "Sum" and add all three columns to the "MAIN TABLE":

```
MAIN TABLE - RESULT/OUTPUT
DoubleValue | Points | Weight | Sum |
-------------------------------------
1,40        | 96     | 2      | 192 |
1,80        | 92     | 2      | 184 |
2,00        | 90     | 2      | 180 |
1,80        | 92     | 2      | 184 |
1,60        | 94     | 2      | 188 |
1,60        | 94     | 2      | 188 |
-------------------------------------
```

The "MAIN TABLE" doesn't need to actually have the new columns "physically" inserted. I would very much prefer if they could just be displayed in the output very much like "SELECT Points * Weight AS Sum" would produce where "Sum" would be displayed but not actually inserted in the table. BUT OK, if it needs to actually be inserted then I will go with that.

How can this be done?

Comment: This looks like a very basic `INNER JOIN`.  What have you tried?

Comment: I did had a hard time figuring out what to try. I haven't done any SQL for about 15 years, so I didn't recall how to do all the INNER JOINS. I only did remember very very basic SQL like SELECT, UPDATE and INSERT.

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for a simpler `INNER JOIN` statement. Please notice that `Sum` is wrapped as it is a *Reserved* word in most SQL variants. Please try to avoid naming items with these words.

```
SELECT m.DoubleValue 
,      s.Points
,      s.Weight
,      [Sum] = s.Points * s.Weight    

FROM       MainTable    AS m
INNER JOIN SecondTable  AS s     ON m.DoubleValue  = s.DoubleValue
```

Comment: OK, thanks for the help. Now I know the basics of doing this but there must be something wrong with this part: "[Sum] = s.Points * s.Weight". At least for me the header for "[Sum]" ends up being "Expr 1004" and every value in the column has "0". I assume you presented the right way to do this, but for some reason something goes wrong.

Comment: Other than that, the columns "Points" and "Weight" are being added to the "MainTable", so that part goes well.